In action method am not getting the values after ajax post call
var obj = {
    RdEmail: useremailid,
    RduserName: username,
    RduserPassword: userpassword,
    RdGender: gender
};
-----------1----------------------
$.ajax({
    url: "Registration/AddData",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result)
        {  
            alert("Registration Succesfull");
            location.reload();
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
       
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
    },
});
----------2----------------------
$.ajax({
       url: 'Registration/AddData',
       type: 'post',
       data: JSON.stringify(obj),
       dataType: 'json',
       contentType: 'application/json chartset=utf-8',
       success: function (result) {

         },
        error: function (xhr) {

          alert('Erro:' + xhr.statusText);
     });


--- Action method ---
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddData(RegistrationData obj) 
{
    return Json(obj);
}

In obj I am getting all nulls.
I need to know what the issue is, and how I can resolve it.

Try adding [FromBody] in front of RegistrationData obj parameter. Also, try not sending stringified data, send it as object. You have typo in chartset=utf-8, it should be charset=utf-8. Those changes should be on second ajax call.

Also, in your second Ajax call, you have a typo: chartset=utf-8 instead of charset=utf-8 (you have one extra "t" in charset ...)

Its working fine once  checked with typo, and after adding [From Body]

The [FromBody] attribute suggested by @MilosStojanovic should in general not be required: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding In my experience, usually a correct Content-Type header is all that you need.

There is more then one transfer ways ! You should decide which one !
Problem resolution called Model Binding for dotnet.
If you are posting JSON Use [FromBody],posting Form User [FromForm]
before parameter type !
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#sources
At Client side There is a confusion i guess!
If you need to send file with form
this is good one for you
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",

but this way can not work with
data: JSON.stringify(obj),
dataType: "json",

Problem; data should be in form of FormData so it is not JSON
Second way is (If you dont need to send data + file(s))
data: JSON.stringify(obj),
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json chartset=utf-8',

